# Airfoils contradict the law of the lever?

Tags: aerodynamics, continuum-mechanics

The law of the lever says that "the less force you use, the more distance you have". It is often exemplified by referring to simple machines, but it should apply to all technical systems. But I do not see that airfoils comply with this principle.

For example, an airplane in steady, level flight that has a lift-to-drag ratio of 20 has to invest 1 N of thrust to obtain 20 N of lift. So the input force is amplified by 20 without having a longer distance to go.

Maybe one can say that no work is done just by holding the airplane up in the air, so the law of the lever cannot reasonably be applied. But the same principle holds true when the airplane starts to climb using lift. In a steady climbing maneuver the airplane gets additional potential energy but has to invest only 1/20 of the force of what would "normally" be required when it would use no lift. Since the thrust only has to be big enough to overcome the drag and not to overcome the weight, the engine can be less powerful, which equals to less chemical energy consumed over time.

I haven't done a rigorous calculation yet, but I am almost sure that an airplane with a very high lift-to-drag ratio gains more potential energy in a climb than what is consumed in chemical energy to produce thrust. That contradicts the law of conservation of energy of course, but I am a skeptic of that principle.

What do you think? Am I on the wrong track?

Comment: @Floris answer is right. It's about energy, not force. The drag experienced by a wing is simply lost energy. A lever is a system that does not lose energy.

Answer (score 4):

Note that the "law of the lever" is essentially a statement of conservation of energy. If you do work over a long distance with a little force, it can (with a lever) be transformed into a lot of force over a short distance.

In the case of a plane, the thrust is used to overcome drag - it has nothing to do with lift (as you point out the plane is not going up or down, and the force of thrust is perpendicular to the force of lift). If you are climbing, then the additional thrust needed for the climb is some fraction of the weight of the plane - the fraction being given by the $\sin$ of the climb angle. If you do the math carefully you will see that the additional work done is exactly equal to the potential energy gained.

The conservation laws are quite broadly applicable. Usually if you think you have found a situation where they don't work, you haven't formulated the problem correctly.